# Base change of nilradical is nilradical

Tags: commutative-algebra, nilpotence

Let $B \to A, B \to B'$ be injective, finite ring homomorphisms (finite means that $A$ and $B'$ are finite  $B$-modules). Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are integral domains. Denote by $N$ the nilradical of $B'$. Is $N \otimes_B A$ the nilradical of $B' \otimes_B A$?

Answer (score 1):

No: let $B=K$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and assume $y:=\sqrt[p]{x}\not\in K$ for some $x\in K$. Let $A:=K(y)=:B^\prime$. Then $N=0$ but

$
B^\prime\otimes_B A=K(y)\otimes_K K(y)\cong K(y)[Y]/(Y-y)^p,
$

where $K(y)[Y]$ is the polynomial ring in one variable over $K(y)$.

Comment: And more generally, a finite field extension $K/k$ is separable iff $K \otimes_k K$ is reduced iff $K \otimes_k S$ is reduced for every reduced $k$-algebra $S$.

Comment: @HagenKnaf Does similar examples also exist in characteristic zero? I am mainly interested in the field of complex numbers.

Comment: If you mean that you are mainly interested in the case $B=\mathbb{C}$ then there are no such examples: an integral domain which is a finite extension of a field is itself a field. Hence $A=\mathbb{C}$ because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and there is nothing to prove then.

Comment: @HagenKnaf What about the case when $B$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra?